# Rendering a collection of different classes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I have a collection that contains instances of several different classes, and I want to render the partial for each instance. I can do this using the following code:

```
<%= render @results %>
```

My question is: How can I render the different partials in a different base directory? The above code will look for app/views/stories/_story.html.erb, however, the partials for this action are all kept in a different directory - app/search/_story.html.erb. Is there any way of specifying this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a helper method like this:

```
def render_results(results)
  result_templates = {"ClassA" => "search/story", "ClassB" => "something/else"}
  results.each do |result|
    if template = result_templates[result.class.name]
      concat render(:partial => template, :object => result)
    end
  end
end
```

And then in the view call `<% render_results(@results) %>`

Answer (score 2):

or you can use is_a?(Object)

```
if is_a?(classA)
 render something_A
elsif is_a?(classB)
  render something_B
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation where I have multiple classes so I use a partial for each class like:

```
for result in @results
  = render :partial => "result_#{result.class.to_s.downcase}", :locals => {:item => result}
end
```

Comment: This is what I use for multimodel search results, with one difference: if you pass `@results` in via `:collection` instead of using a locals and a `for` or `each` block, each object is assigned to its partial's `partialname` variable. This avoids having abstracted variables like "item" (no offense!) strewn about different classes' view contexts and preserves semantic sense, e.g. `school.address` vs. `item.address` within a `school` partial. It's a little more complicated if you don't want to use the default `classnames/_classname` partial location.